# Generate random non repeating numbers in a range except a specific number in python

Tags: python

Is there a method in python to generate random non repeating numbers in a range except a specific number.For example i want to generate numbers between 1 and 10 but "1" should not be generated.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: "Non-repeating" and "random" are mutually exclusive. Random sequences repeat numbers.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Not necessarily, you can for instance generate a random permutation of a sequence. As a result the list is random but non-repeating...

Comment: @CommuSoft: That is a single random "output". It is possible to generate another random permutation that has exactly the same order as the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to exclude `n` in range of `a` to `b`

```
import random
random.choice([random.randint(a,n-1),random.randint(n+1,b)])
```

Comment: When i try to use random.sample instead of random.randint inside random.choice,it throws an error saying sample larger than population

Comment: No need to use `random.sample` inside `random.choice` together . If you need one random choice using sample, you can do `print random.sample(population,1)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) with a population that does not include the value(s) that you don't like.

```
>>> import random

>>> population = range(2,11)   # 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
>>> print random.sample(range(2,11), 5)
[6, 2, 4, 8, 9]
```

Or another example, if you don't want "42":

```
>>> population = range(1, 101)    # 1,2,...,100
>>> population.remove(42)
>>> print random.sample(population, 20)
[45, 10, 86, 7, 79, 39, 88, 80, 41, 85, 25, 96, 68, 55, 5, 74, 8, 9, 65, 18]
```